# UWP app work fine on debug but give error "DllImport" in Release

Tags: c#, uwp

I am reviewing one of [GitHub](https://github.com/mattleibow/Microsoft.Devices.Radio.FMRadio) Project and found a problem, It works fine in Debug Mode Following Error Comes if try in Release Mode

> TypeLoadException: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'MediaApi_GetRadioEnabled!radioapi.dll' in assembly 'Microsoft.Devices.Radio.FMRadio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.

And if i continue or set DllImportExactSpelling=true

then it gives this error

Exception thrown at 0x77654CD7 (KernelBase.dll) in FMRadioTuneUWP.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x8000000B, 0x00000040, 0x077AF890).

and these on output windows at the time of testing release

> 'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\WPSystem\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\34bca468-6b93-4a95-a266-21950d391b90VS.Release_ARM.ps201\FMRadioApp.exe'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\combase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\rpcrt4.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\kernel32legacy.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\PROGRAMS\WINDOWSAPPS\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.4_1.4.24201.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mrt100_app.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\RadioApi.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\oleaut32.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinTypes.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\PROGRAMS\WINDOWSAPPS\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.24123.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vcruntime140_app.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ZTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\sechost.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ZMediaQueueClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\msvcp_win.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\windows.storage.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\advapi32legacy.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\phoneinfo.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\SecRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\shlwapi.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\SHCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\sspicli.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\msvcp110_win.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\MrmCoreR.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\mrt100.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'U:\PROGRAMS\WINDOWSAPPS\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.4_1.4.24201.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mrt100_app.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'U:\PROGRAMS\WINDOWSAPPS\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3_1.3.24201.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\SharedLibrary.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Collections.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.IO.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.ObjectModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Interop.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Reflection.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Reflection.Execution.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Threading.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.TypeLoader.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Uri.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Implementation.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.SharedLibrary.Interop.Generated.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'D:\WPSystem\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\34bca468-6b93-4a95-a266-21950d391b90VS.Release_ARM.ps201\FMRadioApp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'FMRadioApp.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'FMRadioApp.McgInterop.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'Microsoft.Devices.Radio.FMRadio.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.AppContext.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.ComponentModel.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Data.Common.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Globalization.Extensions.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.DeveloperExperience.AppX.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.Networking.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.PortableThunks.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.StackTraceGenerator.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Private.WinRTInterop.CoreLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Handles.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Runtime.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Security.Claims.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Security.Principal.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll'. PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ProcThreadExtHost.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   The thread 0x1784 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ModernApiExtHost.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\PsmApp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WpPortingLibrary.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\MinUser.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\win32u.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\BCP47Langs.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\CoreMessaging.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\gdi32.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\gdi32min.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\xamlpalwp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\AppChromeAPI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ShellChromeAPI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\DWrite.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\CoreApplicationShim.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\AppModelProxy.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\dxgi.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\Windows.Phone.Devices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\EmClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\AgHostSvcs.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\OnDemandBrokerClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\TaskHostCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\TaskHostSvcs.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\wpcoreutil.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\StorageUsage.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\actxprxy.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\Windows.UI.ApplicationTheme.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\d3d11.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\qcdx11um8612.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\msvcr120.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\MrmEnvironmentExt.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\Windows.UI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\dcomp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ShellRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\InputHost.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\SharedData\PhoneTools\11.0\Debugger\bin\RemoteDebugger\XamlDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\SharedData\PhoneTools\11.0\Debugger\bin\RemoteDebugger\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpTap.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\Windows.UI.Core.TextInput.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\TextInputFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\Windows.Graphics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\rometadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\cryptbase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\Windows.Globalization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\msftedit.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\d2d1.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\crypt32.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\msasn1.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ninput.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\threadpoolwinrt.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\rmclient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\directmanipulation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\AppModelCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\ie_shims.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\UIAnimation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.

all lines with PDB file was not present 
and 
0x77654CD7 (KernelBase.dll) in FMRadioTuneUWP.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x8000000B, 0x00000040, 0x07AFF770).

and finally this
Unhandled exception at 0x68645BA5 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in FMRadioApp.exe: 0xC000027B

Comment: Post this issue on that project's issues page, instead of here on SO.

Comment: Try this. Go to your nuget package manager and update the netcore for UWP to the latest `5.4.0`. Let me know how you go.

Comment: yes its work :) 
But when i launch Release version through it show error in output window when i use app            
               
'C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.    
'FMRadioApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\xamlpalwp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Exception thrown at 0x77654CD7 (KernelBase.dll) in FMRadioApp.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x8000000B, 0x00000040, 0x07EFF778).        
             
The thread 0xac8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: You need to @ me otherwise I won't be notified. I see you have already raised an issue with the author, so it's a good idea just to wait him to get back to you.

Comment: @Justin XL yes but your suggestion works by updating netcore except that runtime error Thanks, i can mark this as answer :)

Comment: Feel free to post your findings as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the `Microsoft.Devices` namespace is supported for UWP. Those are legacy APIs for the Silverlight-based Windows Phone 7-8.1 apps.